# How can I use different KeyMaps for Visual Studio 2022 vs Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, resharper, keymaps

This could be a generic question in terms of using different key maps between different versions of Visual Studio but especially relevant with ReSharper not supporting VS 2022 preview  yet.

I have conflicts in common keybindings like <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> which maps to ReSharper GoTo in my existing Visual Studio 2019 with ReSharper installed. But in VS 2022, which seems to be using same keymaps, there is no ReSharper, so <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> does nothing.

If I reset keymap in VS 2022 to default so <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> maps to VS Edit.GotoAll that breaks my 2019 setup where it goes away from ReSharper to VS default (la 2022).

Is there a way to have completely separate keymap for each version? Or is there another way for me to work around this (something I am not configuring correctly etc.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off your settings syncronization under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Accounts`:

[image]

Comment: The option is already unticked in both 2019 and 2022. The situation is with the selection unticked.

Comment: I would think that both versions of Visual Studio would have their own separate local vssettings files, mine for VS2019 is under: c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings - I don't have VS2022 installed so can't check which one it uses.

Comment: I now have VS2022 and it seems that the options are linked to VS2019's. For example, changing the font or theme on one changes the other too. That setting I highlighted seems to have no impact. I have raised this as an issue with Microsoft.